# Save Coordinates in a Text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am using HTML and javascript to draw a line and display the coordinates of that line.

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wTmFE/219/) on jsfiddle.

I want to store these coordinates in a text file instead of displaying them next to the drawing box.
Can you help me figure it out.

This is my HTML file

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black;">    </canvas>
<div id="coord"></div>
<div id="coords"></div>
```

Comment: You can't write to a file on the client side

Comment: Unless there's a reason to use specifically a text file, google for `localstorage`.

Comment: sorry, but without a server-side technology you cannot achieve your task

Comment: I can't create a text file in my html folder and store into it the coordinates ?

Comment: You can't, not with JavaScript alone. Browsers have security measures that prevent you from saving arbitrary files on a user's computer. But if you want to just store the coordinates there are other ways of doing that, like localstorage or server-side files or databases. You can also trigger a file saving dialog and let the user decide where to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

At one point the W3C File API included a `saveAs` method which allows you to save files to a users local file system using javascript.

The `saveAs` part of the File API has now been removed by browsers for very good security reasons.

Eli Grey has coded a nice plugin that allows you to download files (like your points file) to a users local filesystem.  The user must confirm that they want the downloaded file before it's saved to their filesystem.  Again, this is for very good security reasons.

The FileSaver plugin:  https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

You might also check out Juhana's suggestion of using `web storage` (also known as `localstorage`) to store your points data to a "sandboxed" storage area.  The storage area is located on the users local filesystem, but access is restricted to your web page only--"sandboxed". Localstorage does not require a user to confirm the save.