# saving client location into a txt file

Tags: php, html, location, var

i'm trying to write "Latitude" and "Longitude" value to a txt file saved in **my server**

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>

<script>
getLocation();
</script>



<?php
$handle = fopen("location", "a");
foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) 
{
fwrite($handle, $variable);
fwrite($handle, "=");
fwrite($handle, $value);
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($handle, "\r\n");
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

after visiting the html page i get a blank text file each time
i wanted  "position.coords.latitude" and position.coords.longitude to written in the txt file

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103963/save-coordinates-in-a-text-file

Comment: First of all, do not mix javascript, html, php codes in one file. Separate them. You are getting the blank file, because you are not doing anything for that. Your javascript code is not sending your longitude and latitude to your server (php code).

Comment: @amol01 can you please guide me how to do that ? i'm beginner

Comment: You should better do some tutorials before writing the code.There are lot of tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/ for example. There you will find a lot.